# Как сделать чтоб бот брал рандомно ссылку из "базы"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Вот отрезок кода:

```
gifs = ["url", "url", "url", "url", "url"]
gif = random.choice(gifs)
@bot.command()
async def сказать(ctx, *args):
  embed = discord.Embed(description=f"  ".join(args), color=0x8A2BE2)
  embed.set_image(url=gif)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Код должен выводить сообщение пользователя из команды: "!сказать (текст)" и под ним оставлять гифку из указанных в коде. Мне понятно почему он выводить только первую гифку из списка, но я не понимаю как сделать иначе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что у вас рандомизация происходить только при запуске, чтобы это решить, необходимо `gif = random.choice(gifs)` поместить в команду

```
gifs = ["url", "url", "url", "url", "url"]
@bot.command()
async def сказать(ctx, *args):
    gif = random.choice(gifs)
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"  ".join(args), color=0x8A2BE2)
    embed.set_image(url=gif)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```